# Convert Time taken in VARCHAR to Decimal/Float. format of data in varchar column is '2 hours 7 minutes'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a SQL Server DB that is in varchar format and the data looks like '2 hours 7 minutes' or '3 Days 1 Hour 59 Minutes'. I am trying to do some research on how to convert the data into decimal format and am not able to find a relatively simple way to do so. Any help will be appreciated. I would imagine it would take a replace function to remove the keywords, days hours and/or minutes and then do the calculation.

Comment: What "decimal" value would `'2 hours 7 minutes'` be? The *real* problem here, however, is that you are storing English phrases when you want a numerical values. What *other* words could you have? Seconds? Weeks? Months? Years? Fortnight?

Comment: Hi, the decimal value would simply be multiples or divisions of 60. So 2 hours 7 minutes would be 2.12 (hours remains 2 and minutes is divided by 60). The 'other' words is a good point. The data shows me Days Hours and Minutes. And I completely agree with you on how the data is being stored, but I am not storing the data in the table that way. It is a different team altogether. I am just trying to figure out a way to get it into a float/decimal format.

Comment: may 0 appear in this format? for example '3 hours 0 minutes'

Comment: I'd push back on the people producing this data to give you the intervals in a usable format.  Otherwise you'll have to split it, and then use a case statement to multiple - days by 24, hours by 1, etc. Pretty horrible.

Comment: You haven't specified what unit you want decimals in. First Normal Form means you put atomic values in there, not one kind of granularity mixes with a different kind. Which is also the problem with your source data. Days mixed with hours, mixed with minutes, mixed with seconds and whatever else.  You need to settle on hours or minutes or seconds, and figure out the decimals later.  I have to agree with Andrew, push back on the people sending you that data, and tell them it's not in 1NF. Do not just say "lets add decimals" if you don't specify the unit. That's another 1NF violation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help

Here we use a bit of JSON to split the string and the window function `lead() over()` to determine Day,Hour or Minute factor.

**Note**: I use JSON because the KEY is the proper sequence.  `string_split()` can not GTD the proper order.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
 ('3 Days 1 Hour 59 Minutes')
,('4 Hours 0 Minutes')
,('2 Hours 1 Minute')

 Select * 
  From  @YourTable A
  Cross Apply (
                Select AsDecimal = sum(V)
                 From  (
                        Select v=try_convert(int,Value)   
                                 * case left(lead(Value,1) over( order by [Key]),1)
                                   when 'D' then 24
                                   when 'H' then 1
                                   when 'M' then (1.0/60)
                                   end
                         From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(SomeCol,' ','","')+'"]' )
                       ) B1
              ) B
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol                     AsDecimal
3 Days 1 Hour 59 Minutes    73.983294
4 Hours 0 Minutes           4.000000
2 Hours 1 Minute            2.016666
```